# Set color value dynamically in App.xaml style

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

In my Xamarin Forms application I have multiple styles including colours.

App.xaml:

```
<prism:PrismApplication.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
<Color x:Key="primary_colour">#000a3d</Color>
...
```

Which I'm using on other .xaml pages:

```
<ContentPage Title="Menu" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource primary_colour}">
```

My question is, how can I change the colour value (#000a3d) in App.xaml dynamically (it will be different based on client logged in)?
Can I bind that value from App.xaml.cs file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `DynamicResource`, from [Xamarin documentaion](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/dynamic/) it says:

> The DynamicResource markup extension is similar to the StaticResource
>   markup extension in that both use a dictionary key to fetch a value
>   from a ResourceDictionary. However, while the StaticResource performs
>   a single dictionary lookup, the DynamicResource maintains a link to
>   the dictionary key. Therefore, if the dictionary entry associated with
>   the key is replaced, the change is applied to the visual element. This
>   enables runtime style changes to be made in an application.

Therefore your page will be:

```
<ContentPage Title="Menu" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource primary_colour}">
```

and your code to change the colour would be:

```
Application.Current.Resources["primary_colour"] = Color.Green;
```